# Why doesn't java see my annotation?

Tags: java, annotations

So I'm trying to learn the basics of using custom annotations so I've created an empty annotation:

```
public @interface CallMe {

}
```

and a `Test` class:

```
import java.lang.annotation.*;

@CallMe
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Annotation[] annotations = Test.class.getAnnotations();

        if (Test.class.isAnnotationPresent(CallMe.class)) {
            System.out.println("CallMe is present.");
        }

        System.out.println("Found " + annotations.length + " annotations.");

        for (Annotation a: annotations) {
            System.out.println("Annotation: " + a);
        }
    }
}
```

I compile both classes and execute `Test`, but:

```
$ javac Test.java CallMe.java
$ java Test
Found 0 annotations.
```

I'm using OpenJDK 1.6 for this test, if it matters. I've treid both `.getAnnotations()` and `.getDeclaredAnnotations()`, but no results.

Why doesn't Java find the annotation?

(And in case you were wondering, I initially was going to attempt to annotate methods, which is why I made it `CallMe`, but I figured a class level example would be easier to do first).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to annotate your annotation class like this to make your annotation info available at runtime:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) 
public @interface CallMe {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface CallMe {
...
}
```

Comment: +1 Thank you, Target was also useful to find out about.